# Is the statement of this theorem about the limit of composite functions incomplete?

Tags: real-analysis

My book has this theorem on the limit of two composite functions:

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $(a,b)$ be a (possibly infinite) interval and let $u=a^{+}$ or
>   $b^{-}$. If $g$ is defined on $(a,b)$ and $\lim_{x \to u}{g(x)} = L$,
>   $f$ is defined on an interval containing $L$ and the image of $g,$ and
>   $f$ is continous at $L,$ then
>
> $\lim_{x \to u}{f(g(x))} = f(L)$

Why do we restrict $u$ to be $a^{+}$ or $b^{-}$ here? Can't it take on any value on $(a,b)$ as well?

Comment: I think this means we only deal the composition for one-side limits now…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lateral case implies the bilateral case. Take $x_0\in (a,b)$ and apply the theorem to $x_0^+$ and $x_0^-$.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask if

$\lim_{x \to u}{f(g(x))} = f(L)$

for any $u$ in $(a, b)$, sure!

But it's not nearly as interesting a question, since $g(u)$ is defined. If $f$ is continuous at $g(u)$ and defined in the image of $g$, then you probably see right away from the definitions of continuity and limits that the statement holds.

The boundaries of the interval, where $g$ isn't necessarily defined, is where the limit might get weird, and where someone might find it more surprising that the statement holds.